# Links out of Structure Listing in Wygwam is missing trailing slash

Tags: wygwam, structure, listing

When adding a link in Wygwam through Structure Listing, the link is missing a trailing slash. Due to our SEO policy we would like to have a trailing slash in the url's. How to realize?